# Uninitialized string offset notice when generating random GUID

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have a code that causes the above error to show up repeatedly in my error log, how can I correct it?

```
public function generate_guid() {
        //you can change the length of the autogenerated guid here
        //i choose 4 because with 26 possible characters that still gives 456.976 possibilities, if you include numbers ( add 0123456789) to the possible characters you will get 1.679.616 combinations
        $length = 4;
         //charachters used for string generation
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = '';    
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))]; <<-- this is line 92
}
return $string;
    }
```

Comment: `$characters` isn't an array, it's a string.

Comment: @Griffin Strings can be accessed as arrays of characters

Comment: @galchen No, curly brackets are supported, but bad style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))` will generate numbers up to the strings length - but as the string offsets start with 0 the maximum offset is the length minus one. So correct would be `mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)`.

By the way, I would recommend using a characters array generated by `range('a', 'z')` (so you don't have to type it out) and getting an element using `array_rand`.